# Issue with JSON

Tags: php, json

I am getting the value from my JSON like so:

```
$adarray = json_decode($addata);
if($adarray->{'zone'} == 'homepage'){
    $chan = 'homepage';
}else if($adarray->{'subcat'} == 'main'){
    $chan = $adarray->{'cat'};
}else{
    $chan = $adarray->{'subcat'};
}
echo $chan;
```

It the else if and else it works perfectly however, I am having trouble with the first part:

When this JSON data is parsed into the if statement it should return 'homepage' yet it just returns the JSON data back, why?

```
{"zone":"homepage"}
```

Comment: May be you are echoing `$addata` instead of `$chan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried the same code on php tester, and got the correct output. Once see if your code is correct.

Try this yourself on http://phptester.net/ :

```
<?php
$adarray = json_decode('{"zone":"homepage"}');
if($adarray->{'zone'} == 'homepage'){
    $chan = 'homepage';
}else if($adarray->{'subcat'} == 'main'){
    $chan = $adarray->{'cat'};
}else{
    $chan = $adarray->{'subcat'};
}
echo $chan;
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the confidence to realize it was an issue somewhere else, which has been resolved now, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please change your code this way

```
$adarray = json_decode($addata,true);
```

So Now it is converted into array. And you can easily manage the array or get value or data from array

Comment: That would convert it into an associative array, which is not needed for this purpose.